# problem with scrollview content size on ipad in landscape

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, contentsize

In viewdidload I have this code:

```
[methodPanes setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfPages*methodPanes.frame.size.width, 100)];
```

Method panes is set relative to the width of `self.view`.

The problem is that if I load the view from landscape format on the iPad and NSLog `methodPanes.frame.size.width` I get **648** (which is obviously wrong).

Then I have a button which when I click on it it NSLogs `methodPanes.frame.size.width` again once the view is displayed. This is now **924** (more like it).

I'm assuming for some reason the scrollview is loading at 648 wide and then autoresizing to the view width (its set to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth to re-size properly when the ipad is rotated).

My problem is that the content size of my methodPanes scrollview content should be `numberOfPages x its frame width`, but in viewDidLoad it gives me the wrong size for my methodPanes frame width, meaning my contentsize is too small, meaning all of my content doesn't get shown.

So..... how can I solve this? Is there a function that's run after ALL UI components have been loaded and have stopped moving around? Or can I keep a "check" on methodPanes to see if it's width changes, and then adjust the content size accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the width after allowing the run loop to run.  The view dimensions will be updated for the orientation by then.  This is usually enough:

```
- (void)adjustContentSize {
    [methodPanes setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfPages*methodPanes.frame.size.width, 100)];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjustContentSize) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Comment: I can't give you more than +1 :(